# PHP encoding (mcrypt and base64) returning strange characters

Tags: php, encoding

I'm at my wits end here after hours of searching.

My initial problem was that encrypt and decrypt routines I've used many times started returning garbage.

I thought to rewrite them and wrote a small routine to generate an encryption key.

That too returned garbage.

I tried simple base64 encode/decode.  Same result.

I've resaved my pages and ensured that encoding was utf-8 and unicode normalization was set to 'none'.

No joy.

The output tells me that it is utf-8, yet utf-8 decode returns nothing legible.

Here is the key gen.  It should work...but ....arrrgh!  I'm hoping someone can help

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-256', '', 'ecb', '');
$size = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
$key = mcrypt_create_iv ($size,MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

 echo "your key is : ".$key.'<br>';
```

?>

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: ECB - ewwww. This creates a binary IV (charset encoding is irrelevant), to re-iterate Jon, what are you expecting?